# cnx or ctx in koa-routes

Tags: node.js, routes, koa

In Koa, I know that "ctx" stands for context, which encapsulates node's request and response objects. However, in API, in my tutors examples I see (cnx, next) rather that (ctx, next). Could someone explain me about ctx and if there is any difference, as I can't find any materials online? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That's the same thing, it's a function parameter name which ref the same object.